# User profile not showing in SharePoint online UPA

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service

We have a user whose profile is available in Azure Active Directory (M365) but not available in SPO UPA (user profile application). Any suggestions on what could be the reason?

Comment: Whether an internal user or an external user?

Comment: Issue is with Internal user.

Comment: Has the user ever attempted to access SharePoint Online?

Comment: Yes. User is using SPO intranet.